# How to restrict access to paid videos?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, encoding

I have a wordpress paid video site with the e-commerce plugin. User purchases a video, then gets shown a meta box with the video player code linking to the video (using flow player 3). How can I stop access to the paid video files to non-authorized users (if they decide to share the direct link to the video by looking at the source code)?

Answer (score 1):

you need protect this content for that session (and ip), using some technique like security token.

http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few plugins that might help you with your problem.

http://www.magicmembers.com/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/

http://www.memberwing.com/